# Finding the CDF from a PDF with multiple conditions

Tags: statistics

The PDF is

\begin{align}
  f_x(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
    \frac{6 x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{13} & \quad \text{if } 0 \le x \le 1 \\
    \frac{6x}{13}    & \quad \text{if } 1 \le x \le 2 \\
    0                & \quad \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
\end{align}

I want to find the CDF.

Do I just integrate each part so ${F_X}(x) = {4 \over {13}}{x^{{3 \over 2}}}$ if $0 \le x \le 1$, etc.?

Comment: That sounds fine to me

Comment: So there is no problem doing that?

Comment: I don't think so but I haven't done probability theory in a while now but your logic seems sound to me

Comment: Should those be $\text{if } 0 \le x \lt 1$ and $\text{if } 1 \le x \lt 2$?

Comment: Technically yes, the only thing is that you need to be careful about your limits of integration. In particular, $F(x)$ for $1<x<2$ is $F(1)$ plus an integral of the second part of the PDF.